# Do I exist under the aspect of eternity?

Tags: time, infinity, self

Do I exist under the aspect of eternity?

> The work of art is the object seen sub specie aeternitatis; and the
> good life is the world seen sub specie aeternitatis.

Wittgenstein on the unity of ethics and aesthetics (where I got the phrase from):

> The phrase “sub specie aeternitatis” has been coined by Spinoza, but
> the idea can be traced back to Plato.

This point of view is

> abstracted from all considerations of time and place and situated in
> their relationship to God and its attributes

I doubt that includes anything about ourselves, rather than God or the world, but your guess is as good as mine.

- what reasons (for the sake of this system, which philosophers) are
  there to think I do?

Comment: No. We all are soon to be forgotten.

Comment: "Consume my heart away; sick with desire
And fastened to a dying animal
It knows not what it is; and gather me
Into the artifice of eternity." - Yeats

Comment: Sure, why not? You have one, highly personal, knowledge of your existence; others around you have theirs, but "under the aspect of eternity", your existence and the events of your timeline are just as much facts as any other. If Wittgenstein is right (TLP 6.431) from your perspective your death is the end of the world, but *sub specie aeternitatis* your life is a timeless fact.

Comment: What do you mean by "under the aspect of eternity"? It certainly doesn't mean anything to me!

Comment: May I suggest borrowing the idea of representing time as a distance axis and asking, "Across what parts if any of an unbounded time axis would a representation of the 'me' process extend?"  Asking present tense questions about the past and future is awkward without some kind of representational model to mediate.

Comment: "does the question make sense" - not really. You should probably clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: @RodolfoAP: "Everything you fear is gonna end
All your hate and hurt lost to the wind
And it's hard, I know the universe
could be each other's friend
Everything you fear is gonna end
And there might not be a sadder thing
Than watchin' Saturn lose her rings
And black holes slowly dancin' in the dark
It's a song that they were born to sing
About the end of everything"

Comment: @curiousdannii "sub specie aeternitatis" is a common phrase in philosophy. saying it makes no sense because you don't understand it is not even an attempt to do your own philosophy

Comment: "Under the aspect of eternity" is a translation of *sub specie aeternitatis* which was used by Spinoza, Wittgenstein and others to refer to the perspective or apprehension of reality in a timeless way, so that everything is perceived as a kind of eternal present, rather than a flow from past to present to future.

Comment: what a cheerful reply @Bumble thanks

Comment: @RodolfoAP,  What if I told ya that it's not that you're forgotten, it just gets harder to remember you?

Answer (score 1):

So much breath and ink has been spilled on this question of an eternal soul or self. Do I exist under the aspect of eternity? The sages and priests say yes, that the essence of you is immortal.

However modern science has given us no evidence that any eternal, unchanging element of identity persists after death. What we call the "self" emerges from biochemical processes in the brain and nervous system - magnificent networks, to be sure, but networks that will one day cease to function when this body dies.

Our thoughts, memories, dreams and personalities are real phenomena, make no mistake. But they are composed of ephemeral patterns of information, brain states that arise and pass away according to the laws of physiology. We have zero indication that anything about this mortal mind is eternal.

Once we discard the idea of an immortal soul, we can see ourselves as we really are: remarkable primates that evolution has endowed with the capacity for language, culture, consciousness and moral reasoning. These gifts are precious, but temporary.

So do not waste this fleeting life obsessed with imaginary eternity. Make the most of your relationships. Seek meanings and purposes that resonate with your ethics and experience, unconstrained by ancient dogmas. Care for your fellow beings, not because an eternal self demands it, but because their joy and suffering matter here and now.

Focus your energies not on the next world, but on elevating the human condition in the time we are granted under the sun. Accept that while nothing lasts forever, including us, we can still fill our transient lives with passion, compassion and grace. This is my counsel, dear friends - make the most of mortality, the only life you will ever have.

Comment: How about..? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_immortality

Comment: 1. It's a a thought experiment based on some very hypothetical concepts. 2. Even then it's discussed in many places there, it won't work for real life situation of death. 3. You can entertain yourself with such things, why not. It's always funny though how religious people cherry pick some seriously hypothetical scenarios from modern science but reject the science they dislike. Why is that? We all know why ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, then the philosopher you're looking for would be René Descartes. He would say that you are the thing that is wondering about whether you exist, and that this is impossible to be deceived about (which is the highest standard of knowledge). Because there is no power that could deceive you into thinking that you do not exist, it follows that there is no power that could make it so that you had never existed. In that sense, your existence is an eternal fact.

If "under the aspect of eternity" means "from a vantage point where all of time and space is immediately accessible", then those are conditions under which every moment of your existence would be constantly present. This isn't very satisfying in your present condition, since you can't change anything about your past or experience anything in your future, but nothing can erase you from eternity, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: I believe you are mixing pure and practical reason. Descartes proceeded from radical doubt and pure reason i.e. what could be deduced from one's armchair without interacting with the outside world. His conclusion (with a little less ego) is "there is thought". Thought indeed entails time, but in the confinement of pure reason it is finite to the span of the thinking. Deviating to practical reason to speculate on eternity loses the validity of "the highest standard of truth" founded on pure reason.

Comment: You're right that something was amiss there. I said "highest standard of truth" where I meant "highest standard of knowledge", so I've edited the answer accordingly. If that misstatement is what led to the confusion about pure and practical reason, we can leave it at that.

Comment: If not, I would point out that the claim that a thing can exist while never having existed is a pure logical contradiction, meaning that the existence of anything entails the concept of eternity. In contrast, time is a concept that we deal with exclusively by means of practical reason. It's hard to imagine a more ideal example of a thing about which we can easily be, always have been, and possibly always will be massively deceived. Thus, Cartesian "pure reason" demands that it be factored out, so that "do I exist under the aspect of eternity" reduces to "do I exist".

Comment: I’d have to agree. There are a lot of mysteries in physics beyond the standard model.

Answer (score 0):

If life or the reality of self is a form of energy or waves at every level, then my thought would lean towards, yes. Our existence would be eternal because from what I understand energy can’t be created nor destroyed. So that leads me to think that somewhere the energy still exists that has always been just in different forms.Does our  energy transition to a different state of existence like water to gas? The eternal question?????? LOL